# Facebook Site Linking Support

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

When someone posts a link to a web site in Facebook, it populates the link preview box with a photo and some text from the site.

If someone posts a link to *my* site in Facebook, it is generally just get the site's domain name and one of the images that appears on the site. No text appears.

I would like to be able to control what text and images appear in the link. Is there a specification that they use? Can I provide some metadata so Facebook will display what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) is Facebook's developer page on their share function.

Basically there are some simple metatags you can use to optimize what appears on FB

```
<meta name="title" content="title" /> 
<meta name="description" content="description " />
<link rel="image_src" href="thumbnail_image" / >
```

Comment: +1 Also note that the image cannot be a gif or it will be auto-blocked (to prevent animated GIFs)

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to find out that it's simple. I was afraid that I'd have to implement some kind of soap or xml-rpc nonsense!

Answer (score 1):

AND:
The wiki article doesn't mention this, but Facebook CACHES the results of your site for awhile.  So, if you're debugging & doing quick iterations, you either need to wait awhile, or rename the page (index2.html, index3.html, etc) until you find something that works.